# How to synchronize global variable access in Node.Js. Is nodejs is right choice for chat room application development?

Tags: node.js, chatroom, cometd

Is NodeJS capable of supporting a multi chat room application, where clients subscribe to chat room through HttpLongPolling and WebSocket ? When I think about chat room solution, I do see there is need of sync blocks while broadcasting to long polling requests and socket connections when messages are received at diff. frequencies. AFAIK there is no multi-threading and sync block concept in JS, but still to access global variables in JS we need sync blocks. My problem is not to develop a chat room solution but it is similar to it, i.e timely message broadcasting to different users subscribed for  channels. Is NodeJs is a right choice for this ?

I analysed CometD, and it seems a right choice for this solution, where it comes with the solution built in the system with channel concept. But CometD has scale-ability problem, so I am trying nodejs which seems light but need to develop this solution on NodeJs. I don't have to process the message but just to pass it to browser clients.

Any suggestion ?

Comment: maybe https://github.com/learnboost/socket.io/ is what you are looking for, there is also a libraries that are build on top of it

Comment: CometD has scalability problems ? Probably you missed this benchmark: http://webtide.intalio.com/2011/09/cometd-2-4-0-websocket-benchmarks/.
I'll be interested in knowing whether your numbers are greater than those shown by CometD.

Comment: Yes my view about CometD is based on the same benchmark. I am happy with CometD's web-socket benchmarks but, httpLongPolling seems to be a problem as we are expecting more users on httpLongPoll. A solution to support 1.5 million CCUs mix of httpLongPolling and WebSocket So CometD 50K users curve seems to be pretty bad, as latency is increasing exponentially. A distribution of load to multiple instances, needs around 30 instance at 50K users per instance.

Comment: Thanks I found socket.io trying out this now.

Answer (score 1):

I've done several multiuser/multiroom applications using from static files, longpolling (comet), sockets, websockets in several languages (c, PHP, node) and up today the best experience is from NodeJS + Socket.IO.

It's soo easy... becouse Socket.IO adapts itself to available client limitations using from longpolling to websockets or flashsockets depending on him. Nevertheless, the less you rely on longpolling, the best.

You create the Socket.IO server, configure it, and 2 events for room enter and leave (beside the rest of events you want to manage). A quick skeleton of the application would be this one. You need to control users lists, users names, etc... but it can be easily done indexing the user's data by socket.id and managing that hash with connect/disconnect events. "fn" are the client callback functions.

```
var http      = require('http')
  , ioo       = require('socket.io')
  ;

var app = http.createServer();
var io  = ioo.listen(app);

// ... Place here Socket.IO configuration...

var port = 8080;
app.listen( port, function() { console.log( 'Server started' ); } );

io.sockets.on( 'connection', function( socket ) {
    // Management messages
    socket.on( 'connect', function( name, fn ) { connect( socket, name, fn ); });
    socket.on( 'disconnect', function() { disconnect( socket.id ); });

    socket.on( 'joinRoom', function( roomName, fn ) { joinRoom( socket, roomName, fn ); });
    socket.on( 'leaveRoom', function( roomName, fn ) { leaveRoom( socket, roomName, fn ); });
} );


...


function joinRoom( socket, roomName, fn ) {
    socket.join( roomName );
    socket.broadcast.to( roomName ).emit( 'serverMessage', 'a user enters' );
    socket.emit( 'message', 'You enter in room ' + roomName );
}

function leaveRoom( socket, roomName, fn ) {
    socket.leave( roomName );
    socket.broadcast.to( roomName ).emit( 'serverMessage', 'a user leaves' );
    socket.emit( 'message', 'You leave room ' + roomName );
}
```

Refer to Socket.IO site for full description of the functions [Socket.IO rooms](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io#rooms)